# Difference between SPList.ContentTypesEnabled and SPList.AllowContentTypes?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the difference between `SPList.ContentTypesEnabled` and `SPList.AllowContentTypes`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SPList.ContentTypesEnabled**

Gets or sets a Boolean value specifying whether content types are enabled for the list.

**AllowContentTypes**

Returns true if the list supports content types.

The first one can be used to get and set while the second one lets you know wether the list supports content types or not so that you can set the first one accordingly to enable content types.

Comment: but in my case, ContentTypesEnabled has a value of 'false' while allowcontenttypes has a value of 'true'. why is that?

Comment: That means your list supports content types but it is not enabled for your list. which you can enabled by setting SPList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, one last thing, to enable content types from SharePoint, we go to library settings --> advanced settings-->enable content types, but how to configure a list to NOT support content types?

Comment: DisallowContentTypes you can set this property as true or false in list definition be cautious in using this as you are doing this in list definition.